# React BrowserRouter Route doesn't change url

Tags: django, reactjs, react-router, django-urls

I am trying to make my React Router change my actual url. Right now it changes the component but does not change the actual url in my browser

Here is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import PaintingList from './paintings/PaintingList';
import PaintingDetail from './paintings/PaintingDetail';
import PaintingCreate from './paintings/PaintingCreate';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>   
        <Route exact path='/' component={PaintingList}/>
        <Route path='/paintings' component={PaintingList}/>
        <Route path='/paintings/create' component={PaintingCreate}/>
        <Route path='/detailed-view/:slug' component={PaintingDetail}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to make the **PaintingDetail** component point to the **/detailed-view/:slug** path but my actual browser keep displaying **http://127.0.0.1:8000/paintings/sad-man** (sad-man is the slug in this case)

I have even tried to delete this line all together

```
<Route path='/detailed-view/:slug' component={PaintingDetail}/>
```

The component still works but the the browser still displays **http://127.0.0.1:8000/paintings/sad-man**

I am using Django for my backend, I am not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Here is my url.py for my paintings model

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from .views import (
        PaintingDetailAPIView,
        PaintingListCreateAPIView,
    )

app_name = 'paintings-api'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PaintingListCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='list-create'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', PaintingDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='detail'),
 ]
```

here is my urls.py in my Django home folder:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='react.html')),
    re_path(r'^paintings', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='react.html')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/paintings/', include('paintings.urls'))
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying to navigate to `/detailed-view/:slug` ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually sorry guys stupid question.

The problem was I needed to change the component that was the link to the same url to make it work. Here is my PaintingInline component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import '../css/Paintinginline.css'

// react-router-dom <Link> documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

class PaintingInline extends Component {

    render() { 

        const {paintingItem} = this.props
        // console.log(paintingItem)
        // console.log(paintingItem.srcs[0].src)
        return ( 
            <div>
                {paintingItem !== undefined ? 
                <div className={"inline-container"}>     
                    <Link maintainScrollPosition={false} to={{
                        pathname:`/paintings/detail/${paintingItem.slug}`,
                        state:{fromDashboard: false}
                    }}>
                        <img    className={"inline-main-image"}
                                src={paintingItem.srcs[0].src}
                                /> 
                    </Link>
                    <h6>{paintingItem.title}</h6>
                    <a>{paintingItem.size_measurements}</a>   
                    <a>{paintingItem.artist}</a>
                    <a>${parseInt(paintingItem.price).toLocaleString()}</a>

                 </div>
                : ""}
            </div>

         );
    }
}

export default PaintingInline;
```

the url  needed to match the  in the app.js